# Сортировка массивов.С++

Tags: c++

Имеется два массива - Rez и YRez (В Rez храним X-сы, в YRez - соотвествующие Y-ки)
Нужно отсортировать YRez(Y1<=Y2<=Y3...<=Yn) и что бы при этом в массиве Rez лежили X-сы,соотвествующие каждому отсортированному Y.(Сортировка Y-по значению уже реализована)

```
int comp(const void* a, const void* b) {
    
    return (*((int*)(a))-*(int*)b);
    
}



//"Естественный отбор"
void Selection(int* funcX, int* Child, int* Rez, int*YRez, int n, int f ,int* X, int* Y) {
    
    int len = 2 * n + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < len/2 ; i++) 
    {
        Rez[i] = funcX[i];
    }

    for (int j = len/2 ; j < len; j++) 
    {
        Rez[j] = Child[j - (len/2)];
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) 
    {
        YRez[k] = function(Rez[k]);
    }

    qsort(YRez, len, sizeof(int), comp);
    
}
```

Comment: А вот тут с помощью `qsort()` сортировать нельзя! Нужно писать свою функцию сортировки, и при любых изменениях в `YRez` делать такие же изменения в `Rez`.

Comment: Либо как вариант хранить не 2 разных массива а один массив из структуры `Point{ int x, y;}`. А зачем компаратор писать принимающим `void*`? если потом всё равно переводить в `int*`? Сразу тогда писать `int comp(const int* a, const int* b)`

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Comment: @DmitryK, затем, что [`std::qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) требует компаратор с параметрами типа `const void*`?

Comment: Действительно, недосмотрел. Спасибо за исправление.

Comment: Зачем вообще `qsort`в C++? :)